# JQuery to native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хотелось бы узнать для самообразования можно ли следующий код:

```
Car.prototype.draw = function () {
  let carHtml = `<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">`;

  this.carElement = $(carHtml);

  this.carElement.css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });

  $("body").append(this.carElement);
};
```

Написать на нативном JS. В частности не понимаю как на нативном реализовать этот участок кода: `this.carElement = $(carHtml);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё, что существует на jQuery - можно написать на "чистом" JS

```
Car.prototype.draw = function () {
  let carHtml = `<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">`;

  this.carElement = createElementFromHTML( carHtml );

  this.carElement.style.cssText = `position: "absolute";
                                   left: ${ this.x };
                                   top: ${ this.y };` 
              // Если это просто число, ${ this.y }px;`

  document.body.appendChild(this.carElement);
};

function createElementFromHTML(str){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = str;
  return div.children[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

У меня получилось реализовать на нативном JS, по крайней мере, результат тот же:

```
Car.prototype.draw = function () {
  let x = this.x,
      y = this.y;

  this.carElement = document.createElement("img");
  this.carElement.setAttribute("src","http://nostarch.com/images/car.png");
  this.carElement.style.cssText = `
    position: absolute;
    left: ${x}px;
    top: ${y}px;
  `

  document.body.appendChild(this.carElement);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Конечно. JQuery как раз на js и написан.

Для поиска элементов у объекта [document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) есть набор функций таких как [getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp), [getElementsByClassName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp), [getElementsByName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp), [getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp).

Атрибут можно изменить при помощи element.[setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Добавлять элементы к документу можно, например, при помощи element.[appendChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Comment: Я знаю, но не понимаю как можно реализовать данный выше код на нативном JS.

Comment: Ну, будет немного мороки. Если в лоб, то: надо распарсить полученную строку, найти на странице указанный в строке элемент, точнее список элементов. Пройтись по этому списку, сверяя теги и в итоге отобрать нужный.